# Extend div to bottom of page dynamically

Tags: html, css, reactjs, user-interface, mobile

I know this question has been asked before, but the answer to my issue is not `height: 100%` or `height: 100vh`.

I have a page with a nav bar and title, and then a Card under those. Sometimes the card may extend below the bottom of the page depending on the content within. IF the card does not fill the page, I want it to have a minimum height that extends to the bottom of the page.

The classic `height: 100vh` does not work for me since I have a Nav Bar and other things above this Card/div. Sometimes, the nav bar is smaller on different devices, hence why I am looking for it to be dynamic.

I'd really appreciate any help, I've not been able to crack it yet. Currently just using a `height: 60vh` which gives the card some more whitespace but I've not been able to figure out how to make it dynamic. Any ideas

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: There is no issue to reproduce @Paulie_D. I'm starting from scratch and looking for the best practice to achieve the problem described in my post.

Comment: So try something and then come back with an actual problem if you can't manage it. Implementation suggestions is not what we do. Have you tried a simple `min-height: 100vh` on the `body` etc. and the use flexbox to fill the remaining height

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D+remaining+height+body

Comment: Most relevant posts on the search are from 2012-2014. Time has moved on. @Paulie_D

Comment: So? I'm just giving you a place to start. Try other searches.

Comment: `flexbox` is the way to go. In this example, https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/, the main section gets extended to have the footer appear at the bottom of the viewport, but you should be able to easily apply the same principle to your final div element here.